# Using an separate settings json file

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how to use a separate file in Angularjs for settings data.

For example I have a growing list of languages in my service that looks like this:

```
.service('Language', function () {
  this.getLanguageSettings = function(lang){
    switch(lang) {
      case 'english':
            code = 'en';
      case 'french':
            code = 'fr';
      ... //lots more languages here
    }
    return {code: code};
  }

})
```

Can I somehow import a languages.json file and use that in the service?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at http://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: It isn't a translation service I'm building and it's not just languages I would use this approach for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your *JSON* file using `$http.get`

```
$http.get('file.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}, function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.service('Language', function ($http) {
  this.getLanguageSettings = function(lang){
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get('file.json').then(function(response){
      var code;
      switch(lang) {
        case 'english':
            code = 'en';
        case 'french':
            code = 'fr';
        ... //lots more languages here
      }
      if(code !== undefined) {
        d.resolve({code: code});
      } else {
        d.reject("something went wrong");
      }
    });
    return d.promise;
  }
})
```

Then to implement, you can do something like this:

```
.controller('SomeController', function(Language, $log){
  Language.getLanguageSettings().then(function(data){
    $log.debug(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

create a file called settings.js (and import it in the index.html) like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').constant('settings', {
    "english": "en",
    .....
})
```

and inject "settings" in your controllers...
Then you can use `settings.english`